# Changing node version used by npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) and through `n` installed `Node 4.0.0`. I originally had `Node 0.10.24` installed.

I run the following command to uninstall `jest-cli` globally:

```
npm uninstall -g jest-cli
```

and get the following error:

```
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /usr/local/nodejs-binary-0.10.24/lib/node_modules: "jest-cli"
```

This error clearly references the old version of node even though I'm using `4.0.0`:

```
$ node -v
v4.0.0
```

So, how can I tell `npm` to use a different version of `node`?

Comment: What does `echo $NODE_PATH` outputs ? You may have to update it. Consider using `nvm` which makes it really easier to manages multiple versions of node (and the related npm)

Comment: `echo $NODE_PATH` returns nothing. `nvm` I feel messes with the environment quite a bit. I was just using `n` to temporarily try a different node version.

Comment: Can you run `which node` and `which npm` for us?

Comment: @topheman, I solved the mystery (see answers) :) .. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to npm documentation (`man npm-folders`):

When npm packages are installed globally, npm `puts stuff in /usr/local or wherever node is installed.` The documentation then goes on to explain that:

> The `prefix` config defaults to the location where node is installed. On
>   most systems, this is `/usr/local`.
>
> On windows, this is the exact location of the `node.exe` binary. On Unix
>   systems, it's one level up, since node is typically installed at
>   `{prefix}/bin/node` rather than `{prefix}/node.exe`.

So, in other words, npm installs stuff where node is installed.

Running `which node` reveals node's location:

```
$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

Which means that in my case `/usr/local` is the `prefix`.

To confirm that things indeed were being installed on `/usr/local`, I run `which jest` (jest was the global package I was trying to uninstall):

```
$ which jest
/usr/local/bin/jest
```

Which does confirm that indeed the `prefix` (location where npm installs stuff) is `/usr/local`.

Now, we modify npm's config to reflect this reality:

```
$ npm config edit
```

That should open a file with a list of config options for npm. Find and modify the `prefix` line to read like so (make sure the line doesn't start with `;`):

```
prefix=/usr/local
```

Once saved, this file will be located in `$HOME/.npmrc`.

And finally, we can uninstall `jest-cli`:

```
$ sudo npm uninstall jest-cli -g
unbuild jest-cli@0.5.4
$
```